# MySql - intervals for date time

Tags: mysql, function

I have an issue that I can seem to figure out... I have a  stored procedures that is converting the date an item was created[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWNaB.png) to the number of days an item is waiting, then I'm using another stored proc to convert the days waiting to number of hours waiting.

The issue I'm having now is that..I need the hours converted to be in intervals of 12 hours. I only want to insert into the hoursWaiting column if the conversion resulted in a 12 hour increment after the intial 24 hours... look at the image attached (it has hourswaiting... but I need those to only be inserted if it's 24/36/48/etc..).

Calculate hoursWaiting

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE dayHour INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE (DATE(earlyDate) < DATE(lateDate) OR (DATE(earlyDate) = DATE(lateDate) AND HOUR(earlyDate) < HOUR(lateDate))) DO
        IF WEEKDAY(earlyDate) NOT IN (5,6) AND earlyDate NOT IN (SELECT HolidayDate FROM hr_holidays) THEN
            SET dayHour = dayHour + 1;
        END IF;
        SET earlyDate = DATE_ADD(earlyDate, INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN dayHour;
END
```

Calculate daysWaiting

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE dayCount INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE DATE(earlyDate) < DATE(lateDate) DO
        IF WEEKDAY(earlyDate) NOT IN (5,6) AND earlyDate NOT IN (SELECT HolidayDate FROM hr_holidays) THEN
            SET dayCount = dayCount + 1;
        END IF;
        SET earlyDate = DATE_ADD(earlyDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
    RETURN dayCount;
END
```

[image: TABLE BEING USED]